# Increase product variation limit in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to increase the product variation limit in woocomerce.

In existing woocommerce code, The product variation limit is 100.

```
$limit = apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit’, 100, $this->get_normalized_rest_base() );
```

I changed the existing code product variation limit as 100 to 200.

```
$limit = apply_filters( ‘woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit’, 200, $this->get_normalized_rest_base() );
```

It works but when I update my woocommerce plugin existing code changes are removed.

So I want that changes in function.php file. How to do it.

**Base Code
( wordpress/plugin/woocommerce/includes/abstract/abstract-wc-rest-controller )**

```
protected function check_batch_limit( $items ) {
    $limit = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 100, $this->get_normalized_rest_base() );
    $total = 0;

    if ( ! empty( $items['create'] ) ) {
        $total += count( $items['create'] );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $items['update'] ) ) {
        $total += count( $items['update'] );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $items['delete'] ) ) {
        $total += count( $items['delete'] );
    }

    if ( $total > $limit ) {
    /* translators: %s: items limit */
        return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_rest_request_entity_too_large', sprintf( __( 'Unable to accept more than %s items for this request.', 'woocommerce' ), $limit ), array( 'status' => 413 ) );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `apply_filters()` call is for. It's a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) that lets you modify the value.

In this case you want to use `add_filter()` with the `woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit` hook name as the first argument, and then a [callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that returns a modified value:

```
function wpse_304237_rest_batch_items_limit( $limit ) {
    $limit = 200;

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 'wpse_304237_rest_batch_items_limit' );
```

Hooks are the main way themes and plugins integrate with WordPress and eachother, so if you want to start doing custom development on WordPress or WooCommerce I'd make learning them a priority.

Comment: I already did the code now understand what I did wrong

add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 'product_variant_check_batch_limit', 200 );

function product_variant_check_batch_limit($limit){

return $limit;
}

Comment: You’re not changing the limit anymore. You’re just returning the original limit. And you’re setting the *priority* to 200 for some reason. Please read the documentation in my first link.

Comment: okay. Thanks, I am a newbie to WordPress. I applied your code in local. it works. I applied same code in themes/functions.php inside but not working.

Comment: In local, I am using one theme file but test server they used two themes, parent and child theme. I added code in child_theme/functions.php. The product variation limit is not affected so getting an error.

{"code":"woocommerce_rest_request_entity_too_large","message":"Unable to accept more than 100 items for this request.","data":{"status":413}}

Answer (score 1):

We resolve the problem. We created the new plugin named as product-variation-limit-plugin and after then create a new file name as product-variation-limit-plugin.php. Added below code inside of the PHP file.

http://woocommerce.com
    description: This plugin is used for increase the product variation limit while export product from odoo to woocommerce
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Sodexis PVT Ltd
    Author URI: http://woocommerce.com
    License: GPL2
    */

```
function wpse_rest_batch_items_limit( $limit ) {
    $limit = 200;

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 'wpse_rest_batch_items_limit' );
```

We checked on it. The problem was product variant is not synced from Odoo to woo commerce so we created this plugin. It is working properly.

Answer (score -3):

For all of those who want to use plugin instead, I created it: [Increase Product Variation Limit For Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/increase-product-variation-limit-for-woocommerce/)

Comment: Please post code to answer this question locally here on the site. Thanks!